# How can I validate repeatered form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery.repeater

I want to use both jquery repeater and jquery validation library. Here my validate rules:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
rules: {
    title: {
        required: true
    },
    subject: {
        required: true
    }
},
messages: {
    title: {
        required: "Enter title!"
    },
    subject: {
        required: "Enter subject!"
    }
},
errorElement: 'div',
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    var placement = $(element).data('error');
    if (placement) {
        $(placement).append(error)
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
},
submitHandler: function (form) {
    submitForm();
    return false;
}
});
```

but it is not working. Because jquery repeater creates input name like **data[0][title], data[1][title], data[0][subject], data[1][subject]**, etc. Therefore my rules are not working just naming title or subject. How can I validate these name like **data[*][title]** and **data[*][subject]** ?

Comment: I'd suggest using the `data` attribute method of defining the validation rules directly in the HTML of the elements you generate.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment, you cannot set rules from within the `.validate()` method when the `name` is unknown.  (*If the `name` is missing, you cannot use this plugin*.)

[Keep in mind that unique `names` are mandatory for this plugin to function](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations). Any of the techniques below still need a unique `name` on each field.

If simple rules like `required` need to be set, then you can declare them inline with `data` attributes, HTML5, or classes.  `required="required"`, `class="required"`, etc. and the plugin will pick them up automatically.

```
<input name="foo" required="required" ....
```

If you cannot alter the inline HTML, then you can use [the `.rules()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) to add rules to these fields as long as they exist at the time you've called `.rules('add')`.

1. Call `.validate()` on your form to initialize the plugin with your options.
2. Create your new fields using Repeater or whatever method, making sure that all new fields have a unique `name` attribute.
3. Call `.rules('add')` insides of a jQuery `.each()` that is attached to a [jQuery selector such as "ends with"](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) on these new fields.  This will dynamically add the `required` rule to all fields with a `name` that *ends with* the string `[subject]`...

   ```
   $("[name$='[subject]']").each(function() {
       $(this).rules('add', 
           required: true,
           messages: {
               required: "optional custom message"

       });
   });
   ```